# Firebase Function. Get the parameters for the new FireBase function SDK

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

Back in 0.9.1 for Firebase Function we use. event handling the data passed to our function.

Now we snapshots for version 1 of Firebase Function SDK.

```
exports.fcmSend = functions.database.ref('/messages/{userId}/{messageId}').onCreate((snap,context) =>{
  const message = snap.val()
  const userId  = snap.ref.parent.path; //This part is getting null;
```

How do I get the userID from this ref?

Answer (score 1):

it is

```
const userId = context.params.userId
```